# What happens to a white dwarf star if it has mass higher than the Chandrashekhar limit?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, stellar-evolution

What will happen if a white dwarf star has mass higher than the [Chandrasekhar limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit), i.e. 1.4 times the mass of the Sun?

Comment: Depends. [$\zeta$ Puppis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_Puppis) has a mass that is more than 20 times the sun's mass, so there must be something more than just the "1.4 times the mass of the sun" limit you are suggesting.

Comment: Changed the question to ask about a WD exceeding the Chandrasekhar limit. atprra, if you think this changes the intent of your question, please [roll back the edit](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/137872/revisions).

Comment: @Qmechanic This question is not a duplicate (of the question indicated as such above) and should be reopened. It asks specifically what happens to a white dwarf as its mass increases. The answer would comprise of a discussion of GR instabilities, electron capture instabilities and the production of type Ia SNe.

Comment: Hi @Rob Jeffries. I'm a bit tired now. Could I ask you to lobby for a reopening in our chat room?

Comment: see also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/14747/2531

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you just add mass to a cold, completely degenerate white dwarf.

Now one possibility is that the added matter undergoes fusion reactions *on the surface*, resulting in mass *loss* and a [Nova outburst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova). But let's ignore this and assume the added matter "sticks".

If we consider an ideal electron-degenerate carbon white dwarf, then its " Chandrasekhar limit" is either governed by a GR instability at finite density, or by the initiation of electron-capture reactions onto carbon nuclei. The two have very similar density thresholds $(\sim 4\times 10^{13}$ kg/m$^3$), and this sets the real Chandrasekhar limit to be about $1.39 M_{\odot}$.

If the WD mass exceeds this, then either it will collapse and initiate electron capture, or electron-capture will initiate a collapse, since electrons are being removed from the gas and it is the pressure of those electrons that prop the star up.

The final outcome will probably be a [type Ia supernova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Ia_supernova), where the density and temperature in the collapsing WD become high enough to ignite carbon fusion reactions. Because the material is degenerate and degeneracy pressure does not depend on temperature, the reactions can "runaway". The amount of energy released when fusing the carbon exceeds the gravitational binding energy of the white dwarf and the whole thing explodes leaving no remnant (a back-of-the-envelope calculation is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/346092/43351)).

An alternative idea is that electron capture proceeds so rapidly that there is insufficient time for enough energy to be liberated by carbon fusion to blow the star part (e.g. [Metzger et al. 2009](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1127#)). The outcome then will most likely be an "underpowered" supernova that leaves behind a neutron star remnant. This is known as "accretion-induced collapse". This scenario is more likely for a white dwarfs that exceed the mass limit by merger with another white dwarf or by accretion onto a white dwarf with a greater oxygen content, because oxygen is harder to ignite than carbon (e.g. [Tauris et al. 2013](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2013/10/aa21662-13/aa21662-13.html)).

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia

The [Chandrasekhar limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit)  is the maximum mass of a stable white dwarf star. The limit was first published by Wilhelm Anderson and E. C. Stoner, and was named after Subrahmanyan Chandrasekhar, the Indian-American astrophysicist who improved upon the accuracy of the calculation in 1930, at the age of 19.

White dwarfs with **masses greater than the limit undergo further gravitational collapse, evolving into a different type of stellar remnant, such as a neutron star or black hole.**

Also read this nice [lecture](http://jila.colorado.edu/~pja/astr2030/lecture10.pdf).

Comment: Whilst this may be possible, the more usual outcome is likely to be a type Ia supernova and no remnant.

Answer (score -1):

Above the Chandrashekhar limit you would obtain a neutron star: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit

Comment: Explain [$\zeta$ puppis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_wind) then.

Comment: Zeta Puppis is an extreme blue supergiant, one of the most luminous stars in the Milky Way. That is a star with 22.5 solar masses.. not a white dwarf or a neutron star but a type O star.

Comment: I know what it is, but your answer says that anything above the Chandrasekhar limit would make a neutron star which is demonstrably false. The *question* also says nothing of white dwarfs or neutron stars or anything, it just says "a body."

Comment: The question was about if the mass exceeds the chandrashekhar limit. This is a well-defined question, namely take a white dwarf and add mass. You get a neutron star. Or a black hole if you suddenly dump enough mass onto it.

Comment: @Kyle: if you are not satisfied with this reasoning, you might also want to change the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit

Comment: My issue is with your false statement; you claim that *any* object with a mass above the Chandrasekhar limit would become a neutron star, this is observably false. The Wikipedia article covers some details that are *necessary* for your answer to be worth anything (and your comments touch upon the details).

Comment: Note I've just edited the question to ask about a white dwarf.

Comment: @KyleKanos I think the missing part of the definition in the question is what happens to a *cold* star with a mass above the Chandrasekhar limit. Where cold means completely degenerate. Actually, even cold white dwarfs can exist at masses above this if they rotate fast enough. If they were hot white dwarfs, we wouldn't call them white dwarfs!